# Select new / modified rows from table

Tags: database, mysql

Using standard Joomla database functions, what's the right way to select new / modified items from a table? I don't want to use `created > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) OR modified > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)` since I'm not sure that all the new DB types supported by Joomla will accept the `now()` / `DATESUB` syntax.

Comment: How could they be greater than now()? When would they have been modified/created?

Wouldn't you want to just order by created or modified and grab the first X number of that list?

Comment: New is relative. Define what new means to you.

Comment: @DavidFritsch-- you're right, I wasn't careful about my query, was more concerned with the theory behind it. Thanks

Comment: Try this: `created > JFactory::getDate('now -1 day')`

Comment: @Farahmand, I've reopened this. I'd post that as an answer.

Comment: @Farahmand-- please post as an answer and I'll choose it as the correct one. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compare them with `JFactory::getDate('now -1 day')` like this:

```
created > JFactory::getDate('now -1 day')
```

and this:

```
modified > JFactory::getDate('now -1 day')
```